# implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.0.1' 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

When I use

```
implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.0.1'
```

in my library `build.gradle`, the build fails with the error message:

`The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you must update  'android.support.design.widget' and other to latest version

Comment: I have the exact same problem and do not use the 'android.support.design.widget' dependency

Comment: do you have a GitHub demo project?